# Haskell List Comprehension and List Monad

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads

I'm trying to write some self-defined type `Martix a`, which is basically list of lists `[[a]]`. When I tried to implement a function named `colAt`, which should give the vertical elements of a matrix, I firstly used the list comprehension:

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c m = [ e | r <- m, e <- r !! c ]
```

But Ghci told me

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
In the expression: r !! c
```

While the do notation worked perfectly with

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c m = do
    r <- m
    return (r !! c)
```

What caused this error? I thought that basically list comprehension is a syntax sugar of list do notations, but given this error my understanding is wrong?

Comment: By the way I found that actually the ```colAt``` can be easily implemented by ```colAt c m = (transpose m) !! c```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is entirely correct: list comprehensions are indeed just syntax sugar for `do` notation! The issue is that you have not desugared your list comprehension correctly.

To start, let’s repeat the list comprehension for reference:

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c m = [ e | r <- m, e <- r !! c ]
```

Now, I’ll desugar it partially, to move the `r <- m` bit outside the comprehension:

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c m = do
    r <- m
    [e | e <- r !! c]
```

And this is simple to desugar fully:

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c m = do
    r <- m
    e <- r !! c
    e
```

Compare to the correct implementation:

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c m = do
    r <- m
    return (r !! c)
```

The issue here is now obvious. In the correct implementation takes `m`, then for each item `r <- m` in turn, finds the element `r !! c :: a`, wraps it in a list, and then returns it. By contrast, your implementation extracts each item `r <- m` correctly, but then tries to extract each ‘element’ of the ‘list’ `r !! c :: a` — which is in fact not necessarily a list, giving the type error you see. The fix is easy: as in the correct implementation, simply add a `return`, giving `[ e | r <- m, e <- return (r !! c) ]`. Or, more simply, using the fact that `[x | x <- return l]` is just the same as `[l]`, you can rewrite this more simply as `[ r !! c | r <- m ]`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the connections between these two syntaxes so clearly!

Comment: It *can* be syntactic sugar. Section 3.11 of the Haskell Report only requires that a list comprehension have the same behavior as a particular combination of `if-else` expressions, `let` expressions, and `concatMap`. Rewriting a list comprehension as a `do` expression is just one possible implementation.

Answer (score 6):

If you write `e <- r !! c`, it expects `r !! c` to be a list, since you are enumerating over that list, but `r !! c` is an item (of type `a`), hence that would only work if you use for example a `Matrix [a]`.

You do not need to enumerate here, you can move the `r !! c` to the "yield" part:

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c m = [ r !! c | r <- m ]
```

but what you here do is a mapping, so you can use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
colAt :: Int -> Matrix a -> [a]
colAt c = map (!! c)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the ```map``` solution, that is just smart!